# PDO connection not working as expected

Tags: php, pdo

I think this is mostly because I'm new to PHP OOP, but I have a quick question that I can't seem to find an answer for. Since I use the same connection information for several methods, I tired to take out the information and put them into property variables as private and static. However, when trying to make a PDO connection, this doesn't work:

```
class MyClass {
    private static $DSN = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb";
    private static $USR = "user";
    private static $PWD = "password";

    public static function connection() {
        $pdo = new PDO($DSN, $USR, $PWD);
        //more code
    }
}
```

Yet when I enter the information manually, it works fine:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function connection() {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", "user", "password");
        //more code
    }
}
```

So why doesn't using a set of properties work? I spent a few hours trying to get it to work and it just didn't, only to find out that that was the problem. I'm fine with manually connecting but I would like to know why the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check to see if you were getting any errors back from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `self` keyword (along with the scope resolution operator `::`) to access those private static properties.

```
$pdo = new PDO( self::$DSN, self::$USR, self::$PWD);
```

Otherwise you're not referencing the correct variables.

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more information about static keywords.

Comment: hah What a stupid mistake to make. Again I'm new to the PHP OOP. I guess I need to learn when to use things like self and this (tried $this as well but that didn't work). Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! It's a common mistake and a part of the learning process. `:)`

Comment: So for future reference, if I need to access those variables anywhere for any reason (inside the class), I'll always have to refer to them as 'self::$var'?

Comment: If they are `static`. If they're not, you'll use `$this->DSN`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your values incorrectly.

```
$pdo = new PDO( self::$DSN, self::$USR, self::$PWD);
```

Or

```
$pdo = new PDO( MyClass::$DSN, MyClass::$USR, MyClass::$PWD);
```